# Coupling of photons and SC qubits in circuit QED

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-entanglement, cavity-qed

I have been going through a number of articles to understand quantum circuits.I am trying to understand how a qubit gets coupled with the photons? But I am only getting answers of how a qubit gets coupled with a resonator cavity? Does both of these are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photons are basically oscillations in the electric/magnetic field and normally, the magnetic field has little role to play in the dynamics of the qubit. The important part is the electric field that couples with the qubit.
In resonators, each oscillation with a specific frequency will be similar to a photon's oscillation of E field and hence the similarity.

Normally, in qubit measurements, we couple a resonator to the qubit and then couple a transmission line to the resonator. Our "classical" or macro devises are then attached to the transmission line. This constitutes the basic quantum circuit.
Hence, there are two couplings here. One is the direct coupling of the qubit with the resonator. But there is also an effect on the qubit because of oscillations in the transmission line which, again, can be modelled as photons. (Due to coupling between the transmission line and qubit)

PS: Mathematically, this coupling interaction is represented by the James Cumming Hamiltonian.

Comment: also does a qubit gets excited form state 0 to state 1 by interaction with the photons?

Comment: also can you explain the circuit a little more, as for the circuit I'm working with, each qubit has a separate flux line and a readout resonator (which is connected to a feedline),then 2 qubits are coupled using a bus resonator. @NiRVANA

Comment: About the excitation, you can't say if the qubit is in 0 or 1 state, only a probability of finding it in a particular state. So, what we do is show the state of qubit on a "bloch sphere". Basically, its a sphere where north pole represents ground state, south pole represents 1 state and all other points on the sphere represent various combinations of 0 and 1 states. Now, the qubit "moves" on the sphere depending on the energy being pumped and dissipation and also decoherence(phase change between 0 and 1).

Comment: So, basically, yes the qubit state does change but it does not go from 0 to 1. It moves "towards" the south pole when you pump energy into it.

Comment: About the circuit that you mentioned, there are various architectures for qubits depending on the purpose. I have even seen architectures that have all qubits interacting with each other or multiple qubits having a same readout channel. So, in all of these cases, the general process is kind of the same. You try to figure out the master equation by looking at the Hamiltonian for the specific architecture and that gives you the dynamics.

Comment: An easy way to do this would be to consider qubits as a TLS approximation for resonators. That means, any interaction in the circuit can be written as a coupling between resonator ladder operators and then where ever you find quibts, you just replace the ladder operators by pauli matrices.